# Video-JS and Firefox playback issue

Tags: html, firefox, video

Appears to me that Firefox has withdrawn support for HTML5 video. Doing a Drupal site, I integrated the Video-js library. Works OK in IE, Chrome, etc. Firefox appears to not throw an error, and attempts to play. If I set autoplay to true, it will play the audio, but the video is missing. You will see a flash of the video content which is a screen half covered with green raster. I have found this display on several other sites that purport to demo HTML5 Video. There are plenty of docs that say FF supports open format but I cannot find one that plays properly, so I have to assume FF has changed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video
For instance if I put this snippet from the above page in a Web page:

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>
```

The clip apparently loads and there is no error event on the source, but the clip doesn't play and the alternate content is not shown either.
I am wondering if this may be because I am outside of the U.S. or possibly if there is a problem with my Firefox setup.